# Смысл фразы "Синусоидальность дидукционного индуктора некоэмутируется с хромофорной эффузией аксирогентно-адиквантного фотонного триангулятора"

Tags: значение-слов

В школьные годы многие ради шутки учили вот такую фразу: "Синусоидальность дидукционного индуктора некоэмутируется с хромофорной эффузией аксирогентно-адиквантного фотонного триангулятора".
Возник вопрос: а есть ли смысл в этой фразе или это белиберда? О чём вообще здесь сказано, если перевести на русский?

Comment: Эта фраза принадлежит этому товарищу. Была рождена его восхитительным больным мозгом во времена писательства в журнале Хакер.
http://lurkmore.to/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%BB_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 1):

Фраз подобных много. Иногда неспециалисту они кажутся полной белибердой, но в них может быть заложен вполне конкретный смысл.

Эта более напоминает искусственную фразу, просто "фотонный триангулятор" заставляет задуматься о каком-то фантастическом романе...
Фраза широко известна в интернете, неужели вы её действительно учили в детстве?

Answer (score 0):

Дурдом, слепок терминов из нескольких областей знания, да еще и с грубыми ошибками. Далеко научные специальные термины убежали от нормального языка. И это пародия на язык профи от академической науки.